# How to get the value of a textbox starting with "str_hidden_name"

Tags: jquery

I have a text box with id `str_hidden_name_1`. How I can get the value using the id up to
`str_hidden_name` (1 is coming dynamically) using jquery.

Comment: would you have access to the number "variable" (the 1 in this case)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the ["starts with" selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) :

```
$('[id^=str_hidden_name_]').val()
```

If you want to be sure it's an input, you may use a more selective selector :

```
$('input[id^=str_hidden_name_]').val()
```

Comment: Closing quote is missing in selector.

Answer (score 1):

if you have access to which number, you can do this

```
$('#str_hidden_name_'+ yourNumber).val()
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $(function(){
    $('input[id^="str_hidden_name_"]').each(function(){
          alert($(this).val());
    });
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you want this

```
$(#'str_hidden_name' + id).val()
```